How to get Standard Pricebook Id in a flow when triggered from a test method?
Can you help me figure this out? I want to test an apex backend controller method that creates an agreement, or a contract object with other words. Problem is that when I prepare the test data in the tests for the method I insert products, and there is a flow on product creation that tries to query StandardPricebook object for its Id. That to me seems as a problem because it seems that the standard PriceBookId is null because when in test the flow doesn't see the data. How can I workaraound this?
I hope my assumption is correct.
Thanks in advance!

Do you have checked this? - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_getStandardPricebookId:~:text=test%E2%80%99s%20flex%20queue.-,getStandardPricebookId(),-Returns%20the%20ID

Yes, I use this method in the unit-test (the test method) but the problem is that the on create trigger on products fails with the message of missing Pricebook2Id which should be the Standard Pricebook id.

Pricebooks in tests are in a weird superposition of:

kinda a "setup object", so the records exist without you needing to make them in your test
but unable to be queried, and have no accessible Id until you perform DML on it

The fix here is to either update or upsert the pricebook(s) in your test (preferably in an @TestSetup method, but can be done in individual test methods if needed).
So either
update new Pricebook2(Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId());

or
upsert new Pricebook2(Name = 'Standard Price Book') Name;

The second approach takes advantage of the fact that Pricebook2's Name field has the idLookup property. That allows us to treat it like an external Id, and gives Salesforce enough information to update the existing Pricebook2 without us providing the actual Id.
The second approach is the best way to deal with custom pricebooks that your org has created (the only real alternative being maintaining a "constants" file that has the pricebook ids in it, which gets messy if a new pricebook is created).
